# Reading Exif using Python: Possibly Corrupted Field Tag 0x0000 in MakerNote IFD

Tags: python, image, tags, exif

I'm working on a project where I want to read metadata from `.jpg` images, and write them to a file. I took some photos taken on an Olympus TG-4 and tried to read the Exif data with Python 3.

My script says:

```
import exifread
f = open('P8110003.JPG', 'rb')
tags = exifread.process_file(f)
```

I get the message `'Possibly corrupted field Tag 0x0000 in MakerNote IFD'`
I've tried five different jpg files, they all result in the same message. I took the pictures today - are they all really corrupt?

This is does not return an error:

```
import PIL.Image
import PIL.ExifTags
img = PIL.Image.open('P8110003.JPG')
exif_data = img._getexif()

exif = {
    PIL.ExifTags.TAGS[k]: v
    for k, v in img._getexif().items()
    if k in PIL.ExifTags.TAGS
}

list(exif_data.values())
print(exif_data.values())
```

So I assume the camera stores the metadata in some proprietary format Exifread doesn't expect? I just want to read the metadata and store it in a text file, then import into a database. I guess reading it out of the dictionary is an workable solution. Would be interested if anyone could shed any light on why Exifread isn't working.

Comment: I just tried the same script with a photo taken on a different camera - different model and manufacturer - and I got no error.

Answer (score 4):

I was doing some small research because of a similar issue. I know the question is old, but maybe some new person will have the same issue(like me).

**What is MarkerNote Tag?**
The "MakerNote" tag contains image information normally in a proprietary binary format, some of this "manufacturer-specific" were "decoded", but they shouldn't contain information that should be accessible to "outside world".

**Why this MarkerNote Tags get so easily corrupted?**
The proprietary formats could break if the MakerNote tag is moved by inserting or editing a tag that precedes it(e.g add a copyright info or an Exif comment).

**Should I worry?**
Although some of the manufacturers keep important information in this proprietary format(e.g Nikon for ISO Speed), the information is, usually, not important.

**What should I do?**
Just ignore it, it doesn't affect the photo quality or relevant information.